# Wordpress site warning & fatal error - Warning: require(/usr/share/php/wp-stack-cache.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day all.

I’m helping a friend of a friend migrate their website from one host to another. Their previous host provided a .zip backup of the wordpress site and database.

I’m at the stage where the site should now be live with the new host but I’m facing the below issue:

```
Warning: require(/usr/share/php/wp-stack-cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/customer/www/domainnamehere/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/wp-stack-cache.php on line 31

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required ‘/usr/share/php/wp-stack-cache.php’ (include_path=’.:/usr/local/php74/pear’) in /home/customer/www/domainnamehere/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/wp-stack-cache.php on line 31
```

I’ve read various topics online and it seems that the problem was caused by a caching plugin. The solution suggested was to locate the following code in the wp-config file:

```
define(‘WP_CACHE’, true);
```

and either set it to false or remove it…however there is no such line in the wp-config file.

Is anyone able to offer any assistance?

Many thanks,

Nathan

I've read various topics and checked wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the StackCache plugin is unsupported on your new server, but it's set up as a ["must use" plugin](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/must-use-plugins/) and is preventing your site from loading at all.

If you backup and remove the the `wp-stack-cache.php` file from `public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/`, perhaps that will get it working again.